# How to prevent button click inside the label control?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this HTML code:

```
 <label style="padding: 0px 0px!important; text-align:center">
  <span style="color: gray">Some Text</span>         
      <button onclick='alert("Hello!")' style="cursor: pointer;">     
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin btn-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>                    </button>
 </label>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzgqLhpd/1/).

In label control I declared button.Button is clicked when I click in any area in the label.How to make button clicked only when I click on the button it self?

Comment: If you need your HTML as is, you can only prevent the button click with js...
e.g. add a listener on button.click, check event.currentTarget in your click-event and if its not button -> then preventDefault() :) otherwise have a look at the other answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

unwrap label to button like

```
<label style="padding: 0px 0px!important; text-align:center">
    <span style="color: gray">Some Text</span>
</label>
<button onclick='alert("Hello!")' style="cursor: pointer;">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin btn-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xzgqLhpd/2/

Comment: in my case the push pin is going down when I use attitude above

Comment: add style on label display:inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is like so:

```html
<label style="padding: 0px 0px!important; text-align:center">
<span style="color: gray">Some Text</span>
</label>           
<button onclick='alert("Hello!")' style="cursor: pointer;">     
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin btn-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>                    
</button>
```

Just place the button outside the label.

Answer (score 0):

add onclick function on wrapper element with `return false;`

```html
 <label onclick="return false;">
  <span style="color: gray">Some Text</span>         
      <button onclick='alert("Hello!");' style="cursor: pointer;">     
               MY BUTTON
      </button>
 </label>
```